# XMLStreamWriter writeAttribute method throws exception when a colon ':' is included in the attribute name

Tags: java, xmlstreamwriter

I am getting exception "Invalid name character ':' (code 58)) in name ("xmlns:xsi"), index #5" for the following statement. If I'm doing this wrong, what is the correct syntax to get the output like: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

`writer.writeAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");`

Comment: You need to use one of the other `writeAttribute` methods (either the 3 string or 4 string variant). However, it looks like you're registering a namespace, then you should use `writeNamespace` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel writeNamespace() resolved my issue.